# Git in multiple subdirectories

Tags: git

So I have a app structure like this:

```
App A (Repo A)
|
|-----App B (Repo B)
|
|-----App C (Repo C)
```

Now I have Site B and Site C in the .gitignore and it worked...for a while but now when I run `git status` on Site A...it is complaining about Site B and Site C (see image)

[image: git status on Site A]

Now I am AWARE of `subtree` and `submodule` for git but from what I understand each of these require some sort of connection between parent-child which is not what I want.

I literally just want to have the directories ignored and if I need to run a `git pull` or something else in Site B or Site C then I will just go into those directories and run it.

TIA!

Comment: You should probably include the top level `.gitignore` file you are using.  Generally speaking, if sites B and C represent separate projects/repos, then they either should not be subdirectories of another Git repo, or maybe you should make them submodules.

Comment: The fact that `git status` reports "_untracked content_" and "_new commits_" suggests that Site B and Site C already are submodules. Are you looking to revert that?

Comment: Oh dios mio.... what have I done lol. Maybe? Where would I find that submodule (lets say I have another server that may still have the correct structure)

Regarding the .gitignore here is a snippet:
`/site-b/*`
`/site-c/*`